# Как ускорить работу кода?

Tags: python

Ниже на пяти языках записан алгоритм. Получив на вход число x, этот алгоритм печатает два числа: a и b. Укажите наименьшее из таких чисел x, при вводе которых алгоритм печатает сначала 2, а потом 3. Допускается диапазон значений для величин целого типа: от −2^31 до 2^31 — 1.

чтобы решить задачу изменил код и сделал перебор каждого значения, но их слишком большой диапазон

как ускорить?

```
for x in range(-2**31,2**31-1):
    i=x
    a = 0
    b = 0
    while x > 0:
        с = x % 2
        if c == 0:
            a += 1
        else:
            b += 1
        x //=  10
    if a == 2 and b==3:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while x > 0:
```

Сюда управление попадёт только при положительном `x` и только тогда изменятся `a` и `b`. Зачем тогда перебирать отрицательные значения `x`, если от этого ничего не зависит? Диапазон перебора можно начать хотя бы с `0`:

```
for x in range(2**31-1):
```

Далее у вас в этой строке буква `с` - русская, поэтому в следующей строке будет ошибка - там буква `c` - английская и интерпретатор считает, что этой переменной ничего не присвоено, это ведь разные переменные:

```
        с = x % 2
        if c == 0:
```

Исправьте обе переменные `c` на одинаковые и лучше если английские.

После этого ваш код моментально начинает находить подходящие значения.

Да, и чтобы прекратить перебор после первого найденного числа добавьте `break`:

```
    if a == 2 and b==3:
        print(i)
        break
```

Comment: Ещё можно не хило так ускорить перебор, если начинать не с нуля, а с `10**(a+b-1)`. Ведь искомое число должно содержать не менее `a+b` цифр.

Comment: @GrAnd Да там нечего ускорять, в Google Colab за порядка 15 миллисекунд этот код отрабатывает и так уже ))  Но вы молодец, что алгоритмически разобрались с задачей, мне лениво было.

Comment: Для данных конкретных a и b - да, пятизначное число найдётся быстро. Надо было задать поиск на все 10 разрядов. :)

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то, если понять "алгоритм на пяти языках", то можно банально вывести обратную формулу и не морочиться с перебором.

Расчёт в виде числа:

```
print(10**(a+b-1) + sum(10**i for i in range(b-1)))
```

или строки:

```
print('1' + '0'*a + '1'*(b-1))
```

Ведь согласно алгоритму переменная `a` будет содержать количество нулей в числе (наименьшее чётное число оканчивается на `0`). А `b` - количество единиц (наименьшее нечётное - `1`).

Т.е. искомое число должно состоять только из **нулей** и **единиц**. И наименьшее значимое число из нужного количества цифр (2+3=5 в данном случае) будет - **10011**. Нули слева быть не могут (иначе число "закончится" раньше чем за 5 итераций), так что там должна стоять единица. А остальные единицы должны стоять справа, чтобы число было наименьшим.